# Sigma Algebra Complement of a set

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ .
We want to show that $\mathcal{B}=\left \{ B\subset Y:f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A} \right \}$ is a sigma algebra , known that $\mathcal{A}$ is sigma algebra.Can someone help me prove that if $B\in \mathcal{B}\Rightarrow B^{c}\in\mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: We have $f^{-1}(B^c)=f^{-1}(B)^c$, and if $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A$, then $f^{-1}(B)^c\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: But we want to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is sigma algebra , what you assumed is used in order to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is sigma algebra.

Comment: No, it assumes $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and shows that $B\in\mathcal B$ implies $B^c\in\mathcal B$.

Comment: oh yes , a set belongs in $\mathcal{B}$ if $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$ and we know that $f^{-1}(B)^{c}=f^{-1}(B^{c})$ so $B^{c}\in \mathcal{B}$ ??

Comment: That is correct.